# Outcome column mapping in tbl_testresult table

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS_Defaultcollection database to get test results data.

I use the table tbl_testresult and column "Outcome" to see outcome of test result. Outcome is listed as  "1", "2". I am expecting to see the outcome something like  "Passed" or "Failed" etc.

I want to know which table has this mapping of numbers (1,2...) to results (Passed, Failed...) in TFS_DefaultCollection Database .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the definition in the TFS 'Warehouse Database', you can get it from the DimTestResult or DimTestResultAttributes tables. Your warehouse database may be on the same SQL Server as your default collection.

e.g.

```
select distinct Outcome, OutcomeId
from DimTestResult
```

Results

```
Outcome         OutcomeId
Failed          3
Passed          2
Aborted         6
Blocked         7
Never Run       255
In Progress     1
Not applicable  11
Paused          12
```

Comment: Just for additinal Info: Inconclusive 4
Timeout 5
NotExecuted 8
Error 10